# GTK# and PixbufAnimation iteration

Tags: time, iterator, gtk#, pixbuf

Greetings,

I'm having a problem using Gdk.PixbufAnimationIter of a PixbufAnimation. The code goes something like this:

```
Gdk.PixbufAnimation animation = new Gdk.PixbufAnimation(System.IO.Path.Combine([filepath], [filename]));
Gdk.PixbufAnimationIter iter = animation.GetIter([Current Time as IntPtr]);
```

Here's what I read about PixbufAnimation.Iter:

> `start_time` is the start time specified
>   as a float as output from the Python
>   `time.time()` function. `start_time` marks
>   the beginning of the animation
>   playback.

GTK# does not have the `time.time()` function, and I have tried the following:

```
long StartTime = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
IntPtr SysTime = new IntPtr (&StartTime);
Gdk.PixbufAnimationIter iter = animation.GetIter(SysTime);
```

But that does not seem to retrieve any time consistently. The numbers generated from this seem very random, and are probably pulling from the wrong address in memory (only a guess, don't quote me on that).

I have also read this from another documentation of PixbufAnimation:

> As a shortcut, if start_time is `NULL`,
>   the result of `g_get_current_time()`
>   will be used automatically.

However, the compiler refuses to allow a `NULL` value for the IntPtr.

I have also read that the "Current Time" is only used if you are trying to mess with the animation, such as making the animation display faster or slower.

Can anyone out there help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass IntPtr.Zero to the GetIter method, that should be the same as passing NULL to the C method.  This API is a little lacking in the binding, to be honest, as the start_time parameter is supposed to be a GTimeVal which is unbound in glib-sharp as yet.  You could certainly file a bug for this and we can extend the API.  We could probably use a GetIter() overload, for example, to handle this scenario more cleanly.

Comment: Thank you, and the funny thing was that I was originally using IntPtr.Zero just to get my code compiling, but I felt that my animation was not displaying correctly because of it. However, that is not the case. Through debugging, I can see that the animation is itering correctly and grabbing the correct pixbufs and delay times, however the pixbuf can not be re-drawn on the window after initialization. It seems that if you do not use Gtk.Image or Gdk.Image, you really have very few options for handling animations, much less animations which require adding an alpha color.